# In a modern SharePoint page: Create URL based on user input and launch that URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, url, modern-pages, microsoft-flow, inputformtextbox

Today I have a classic SharePoint page where the user can enter a number in an input box and press a button to launch a page where this number is appended to the URL of the page.
This was a very simple javascript,  it was just displaying an input box and the script would just append the number entered by the user so the end result would be like: https://xxx.xxx.com/tfs/Products/MyProduct/_workitems/edit/123456/ and then launch that page.

Now, when I need to migrate this functionality to a modern page, where I cannot use javascript anymore (and SpFx is not allowed on the tenant), I am thinking about different other solutions.

First I thought about creating a list and display only one row (to get an input box where the user could input the number) and then using a calculated field and use json to format an URL with the number that the user could click on to get to the page.
But actually I do not want to save a lot of numbers that the users have searched for in a list, and most users do not even have write access to this site. I can arrange write access on this list of course, and clean it often.

Then I came to think about Flow. How about starting a flow after the user entered the number as an item of the list, then building the URL, launching the URL and sending the item straight to the recycle bin?
Is this possible in Flow? Will it be fast enough or is flow too slow? Also I do not want to bother the user with mails about this.

Other out-of-the-box suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not seeing other options if your tenant forbids using SPFx.
Microsoft flow is possible for formatting an URL but there is no action to open a webpage in Flow for the time being.

I will give a vote for list records, with calculated column and JSON formatting, which might be the easiest and quickest way to finish this task.

If you worry about too many records in the list, consider using [Information Management Policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/create-info-mgmt-policies?view=o365-worldwide)/Retention Policy to auto-clean this list.

Comment: Column formatting does not seem to work in grid view, only in regular views where the user first needs to press "New" to add a new item. By using the grid view I was hoping to make the list look like an input field. But maybe it is possible to format the column in the regular view like an input box?

Comment: @Gunilla I’m afraid that is not column formatting is meant for, which is more about displaying. The formatting will not show in the field which you are filling in grid view since you are in Edit mode. See what you can do with JSON format here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting